# Searching Large Array Performance in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a a JSON file of all the airports in the world that I am trying to search in a function but it is very slow and am trying to improve its performance. There are 9500 entries in this JSON file( I would have used an web API but couldnt find a free one so I am using this JSON file). My array is like like:

```
var data = [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
```

Here is what one of the dictionaries looks like:

```
[DisplayText: YYZ, airportObject: {
    0 = 193;
    Altitude = 569;
    City = Toronto;
    Country = Canada;
    DST = A;
    IATA = YYZ;
    ICAO = CYYZ;
    Latitude = "43.677223";
    Longitude = "-79.630556";
    Name = "Lester B Pearson Intl";
    TZ = "America/Toronto";
    UTC = "-5";
}, DisplaySubText: Lester B Pearson Intl]
```

The goal is to have a TextField autocomplete with the name of the airport as the user types in the field. I wrote a function to filter these entries with the user's input. It works, however it is very slow and takes about 1 second per letter typed, and the cpu goes to 50% when typing.

Here is the function

```
func applyFilterWithSearchQuery(filter : String) -> [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
{
    //let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "DisplayText BEGINSWITH[cd] \(filter)")
    var lower = (filter as NSString).lowercaseString
    var filteredData = data.filter({
            if let match : AnyObject  = $0["DisplayText"]{
                //println("LCS = \(filter.lowercaseString)")
                return (match as NSString).lowercaseString.hasPrefix((filter as NSString).lowercaseString)
            }
            else{
                return false
            }
        })
    return filteredData
}
```

How can I improve the performance of this function?

Comment: I would split the file into smaller for example copy all airport which start with A to a.json, B to b.json and so on. And when user start typing search just the file with the first letter the user typed.

Comment: Only you can determine that. Use Instruments! Tweak and test! But one obvious suggestion is: don't repeat things in the filter that you could do beforehand. Take the `lowercaseString` beforehand, for example. (Why are you taking `lower` and not even using it???) Also, you may find that NSString's methods for determining whether `match` starts with `filter` are faster than `hasPrefix`.

Comment: Put the JSON file into a database file (CoreData would be easiest) and use `NSPredicates` on a fetch request.  Stop repeatedly converting filter to lower case, use your preconverted version instead.  Cache the results from one go to the next (no need to filter your full list for AB* when you already have a list of A*, just refilter your sublist)

Comment: Convert the array of dictionaries into an array of Airport structures, in my tests that reduced execution time to about a third.  Make sure you're not trying to do performance evaluation in the playground.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up taking all the comments into account and came up with this.

1. I changed the logic so it only only runs applyFilterWithSearchQuery after 2 characters are typed instead of 1.
2. Cached the results after each result so only the sublist was searched
3. Changed the function to use NSPredicate as per below:

```html
    func applyFilterWithSearchQuery(filter : String) -> [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
    {
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "DisplayText BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", filter)
        let filteredData = (self.data as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate!)
        return filteredData as [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
    }
```

Overall CPU time dropped down to 1% . Thanks to all those that had suggestions